# Flight at 00:20, but passing through Immigration before midnight

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, schengen-visas

I have a German national visa that will take effect from March 1, 2017 up to August 31, 2017. I want to arrive there as early as possible, so I'm taking the earliest flight which is just 20 minutes after midnight, that's early on March 1, 2017. However, I'll surely pass by the Immigration Officer before midnight so then  still February 28, 2017.

Will they let me board the plane or will that be a problem?

Comment: Do you mean your flight arrives on 1 March (that you board on 28 Feb)?

Comment: No, my only concern is I'll surely pass by the immigration before midnight, and that's still February 28. My flight leaves at 00:20 on March 1. I will arrive in Amsterdam at 12:40 on March 1.

Comment: "Next question" - please ask that as a separate question. Otherwise, different answers might provide the best answer for separate sub-questions of yours, and it will be impossible for you to mark more as one answer as "accepted" (meaning "presumeably the best answer").

Comment: Noted, I edited the question :)

Comment: You go through immigration upon arrival, so is it the airline you're worried about? It should be okay, as carriers understand that your arrival will coincide with your visa's validity. At Immigration in Amsterdam, your visa says March 1, you arrive March 1: Van harte welkom om de Nederland!

Comment: Yes, I'm worried that they won't let me board the plane because it'll be just before midnight when I board (presumably).

Does this mean that I CAN fly from February 28, as long as I arrive in the Schengen area and pass by the immigration on March 1? @Dorothy

Comment: Yes, it should not be a since the airline knows you _arrive_ on the right date. Out of curiosity, what airline, and from where (departure city)?

Comment: I'm looking at Emirates (since they have the earliest flight on March 1). And I'm going to depart from Metro Manila, Philippines. 

However, with the information you provided, I think I'm going to purchase a ticket from February 28 and arrive on March 1. :) @Dorothy

Comment: That is a very long haul and a departure that gets you there the next day is not unusual and Emirates is very experienced in this sort of itinerary (and we don't do chats, so have a great trip :-)

Answer (score 2):

Your Schengen visa counts from when you pass through immigration into the Schengen area.   The airline will allow you to board as they understand the rules.  And if by chance your country's immigration checks that you have the proper documents, they also allow departure for the same reason.

Likewise at the end of your stay, the date and time you pass out through German immigration determines your compliance with your visit limits, not the time your plane takes off.

As a side note, in countries such as the US where there are no exit formalities, the flight departure time & date counts as your official exit time.

Comment: "Your German visa counts from when you pass through immigration in Germany" - My university in German is near the border for the Netherlands. Thus, I'm flying to the Schengen area through Amsterdam. Are you saying that they won't count until I reach germany? I'm planning to travel for a week before going to Germany.

Comment: @DavidJ. This should be: "when you pass through immigration in the Schengen area".